# What is the Name of the Function $f(x) = \frac{x + |x|}{2}$

Tags: functions, terminology, absolute-value

I'm dealing with a function that can be written in all of the following forms:

$$f(x) = \frac{x + |x|}{2} \\
= x\ \Theta(x) \\
= \int_{-\infty}^x \Theta(y) \operatorname{d}y,$$

where $\Theta(x)$ is the standard unit step (Heaviside) function. Does the function $f(x)$ have a special name?

Comment: It is known as a ramp function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function

Comment: Along side ramp function, this function is $\max(x,0)$ and it is also $f^+(x)$, where $f(x)=x$.